# How to restart app in PM2 without actual files on disk

Tags: node.js, pm2, nodejs-server

Is there a way to configure `PM2` to restart app by the files from it's last start which are in the memory?

The reason for this is that I want to remove my source codes from server.

If not, it would be awesome if you mention some alternative memory-based ( RAM ) ways to restart nodeJs app without actual files on disk. ( not obfuscate or encrypt or compile or anything like that )

Thanks

Comment: A) This sounds sketchy to an extreme. B) No.

Comment: @tadman do you have any reason why it's dangerous? most of the files ( not all of them ) are in memory as long as nodeJs is running

Comment: A restart is a stop and start pair, so if there's nothing to start, good luck starting it.

Comment: What happens when server reboots ? Nothing persists in RAM

Comment: If your intention is to remove your source code from the server maybe you are using the wrong language? I am in the same position so I had to switch over to Go for generating binaries

Comment: @ManosKounelakis it's not a server-reboot. it's a nodejs restart.